# Bug with MaterialDatePicker Edittext hint

Tags: android, user-interface, material-ui, datepicker, materialdatepicker

I'm trying to figure out why this issue is occurring with the MaterialDatePicker when selecting the edit icon to input a date manually. I get a visual bug with the date hint, it looks like there is a standard hint in grey that says m/d/yy and then another hint in black that says Date and they are overlapping each other.

Has anyone else seen this and/or have a solution for it?

```
val pickerBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().build()
pickerBuilder.show(childFragmentManager,"dp")
```

[material date bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ6w4.png)

Comment: Could you please also add the material library version you are using because i have the same date picker in one of my application and seems to be working great.

Comment: add your code to check the implementation

Comment: @MalikSaifullah it's version 1.6.1

Comment: @davidte the code is there, I just take the standard material date picker, build it and show it.

Comment: @Jesse unable to reproduce on same version hope some one here has the issue and we get reproduction steps and provide a solution for it till then good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles upon this thread as I did, here is the Github issue connected to this problem:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/3625

The issue appears closed but its not yet resolved, there is still a PR open which hopefully makes it into an upcoming release, at the moment the only "workaround" except for waiting for the fix is to downgrade the material lib to 1.9.0, would not do that personally but if you really want this to work.